# libboost & libsigc installation error on ubuntu 22.04 Lts

Tags: 22.04

how to fix the problem libboost-iostreams1.74.0' has no installation candidate E: Package 'libsigc++-2.0-0v5' has no installation candidate?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full command you used trying to install the packages.

Comment: @user535733 they're both in `main` I think?

Comment: @steeldriver you're right again! Newer versions of libboost-iostreams are in Universe.